# XSL, get current working directory

Tags: xml, xslt, directory

I'm looking for a concrete example of an XSL stylesheet storing the current working directory into a variable.

I need this because in my situation, I need to import certain library stylesheets using a relative path. Knowing the path my processor is choosing as the current directory would be sufficient.

EDIT

Nothing vendor specific please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In XSLT 2.0 one can use the standard XPath 2.0 function [resolve-uri()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-resolve-uri).**

**Do note, that the relative URIs of the included/imported stylesheet modules are relative to the *base URI* of the including/importing stylesheet module -- not from the "working directory"!**

Here is part of the description of this function from the W3 F&O specification:

> 8.1 fn:resolve-uri
>
> fn:resolve-uri($relative as
>   xs:string?) as xs:anyURI?
>
> fn:resolve-uri($relative as
>   xs:string?, $base as xs:string) as
>   xs:anyURI?
>
> Summary: The purpose of this function
>   is to enable a relative URI to be
>   resolved against an absolute URI.
>
> The first form of this function
>   resolves $relative against the value
>   of the base-uri property from the
>   static context. If the base-uri
>   property is not initialized in the
>   static context an error is raised
>   [err:FONS0005].

**Here is a very simple example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select=
   "resolve-uri('resolve-uri-example2.xsl')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied against any xml document (not used), the result is**:

```
file:///c:/tests/resolve-uri-example2.xsl
```

This is the correct result, because our main stylesheet module is saved as:

```
c:/tests/resolve-uri-example2.xsl
```

Comment: thanks dimitre, could you please provide a concrete example of using it to determine the current path. i can't see how to do this from the documentation

Comment: Thank you dimitre, as always I appreciate your thorough help with my xslt issues.

Comment: @Mike: You are welcome. Hope my answer has been useful to the extend that you would upvote and accept it. :)

Answer (score 3):

In the XSL world there's no guarantee that an absolute current working directory exists, or even that the concept has meaning.  Any answer to this question would necessarily be vendor-specific.

Comment: @Jim-Garrison: Actually, your answer generally isn't true.

Comment: @Dimitre: Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: @Jim-Garrison: What the OP is actually asking is the *base-uri* of the xslt stylesheet module, not the working directory.