# Get current working directory for XSLT v1.0?

Tags: xslt

How can I retrieve the current working directory with XSLT version 1.0?
I have already looked at these posts here:
[XSL, get current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910389/xsl-get-current-working-directory)
[How to get current document uri in XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477262/how-to-get-current-document-uri-in-xslt)

But it requires version 2.0 and I am not sure if I have that as when I tried switching to 2.0 I get an error.
Here are the XSL snippets I tried:

```
<xsl:variable name="myURI" select="resolve-uri('my.xsl')"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:variable name="myURI" select="document-uri(document(''))" />
```

and in both cases I get errors:

```
Error! Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(resolve-uri, [literal-expr(junit-frames.xsl)])'.
Fatal Error! Could not compile stylesheet

Error! Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(document-uri, [funcall(document, [literal-expr()])])'.
Fatal Error! Could not compile stylesheet
```

Then I also saw this post here: [xslt get the file current folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546152/xslt-get-the-file-current-folder-path)

But as I am an XSLT newbie I don't understand the answer or how to implement it. Can anybody provide an example snippet? Thanks!

Comment: What xslt processor are you using?

Comment: I am not sure, it's the one which comes with Ant 1.8.2.

Comment: "I tried switching to 2.0" - it's not enough simply to change the `version="1.0"` to `version="2.0"`, you need a processor that supports XSLT 2.0, such as [Saxon](http://saxon.sf.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say in a comment that you're using the processor "which comes with Ant 1.8.2".  In that case the simplest answer may be to pass in the current directory as a parameter

```
<xslt style="stylesheet.xsl" in="in.xml" out="out.xml">
  <param name="basedir" expression="${basedir}" />
</xslt>
```

and in your stylesheet add a top-level

```
<xsl:param name="basedir" />
```

Now you have access to the current directory path as `$basedir`.

If you need the path as a URI rather than a native file path you can use `makeurl`:

```
<makeurl file="${basedir}" property="basedir.url" />
<xslt style="stylesheet.xsl" in="in.xml" out="out.xml">
  <param name="basedir" expression="${basedir.url}" />
</xslt>
```